# Java JTable data from database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm new to java and I need help with displaying a joined table/query in jtable.

First, I have done displaying data from 1 table which is:

- Select data from 1 table
- insert the result to its entity and insert each one of it to a List
- return the list to view and insert row to jtable

I am using a DAO pattern, which has a factory, interface, implement, entity and view.

So what if I select data from other table?

Here is my get method in implement for getting book

```
 public List get(String find) {
    try {
        ps = db.connect().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title like ? ");
        ps.setString(1, "%" + find + "%");

        status = db.execute(ps);
        if (status) {
            books = db.get_result();
            listBooks = new ArrayList<>();

            while (books.next()) {
                entity_books b = new entity_books();
                b.setId(books.getInt(1));
                b.setId_category(books.getInt(2)); 
                b.setTitle(books.getString(3));
                listBooks.add(b);
            }
            books.close();
            return listBooks;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then in my view:

```
listBooks = booksDAO.get(find.getText());
    model = (DefaultTableModel) book_table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);

    listBooks.forEach((data) -> {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            data.getId(),
            data.getId_category(),
            data.getTitle(),

        });
    });
```

This works fine, but I want the query to join table so I can see the category name instead of just ID category. I can do the query, but how do I apply that to my code?

Here is the query for joined table

```
select title,category from book b
join category c on c.id = b.id_category
```

Normally if I select only 1 table, I would insert it to its entity ( book table -> book entity ), so how do I handle this with multiple tables?

Comment: any help / suggestion / clue on how to do this would be really helpful , thanks :)

Comment: can you clarify your question as a summery?

Comment: how do i handle the result from joined query in jave ? because if it only one table , i insert the result to its own entity class like in my code above.

Comment: This is really a broad question. There is a whole class of libraries (ORM) that does things like this (eg Hibernate), and they aren't simple.

Comment: So without a complicated code / using library , there is no simple way to use joined table ? but there is simple way to just use 1 table like above ? or do i misunderstood ?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it will either be brittle, or complex, and you haven't even shown an attempt to solve this yourself. To provide a good answer would require a (very) long answer, which makes it too broad. Also, I don't see how the answer you accepted answers your question at all; it just shows you to get data from a joined query... (which isn't different from a query to a single table).

Comment: Whoa , first i'm sorry if i'm looking like i am not trying at all. but i do and stuck so i ask here. All i need is a clue or suggestion where to store the result set of multiple table which if it only one table then i store it in one entity class ( which my lecturer teach me ). The accepted answer give me a clue to store it in list inside list ( which then i don't use any entity class ) but at least it work. again this is not about the query , i just need help about where to store the data to return to other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use prepared statement, but this code works on my end.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer c JOIN company cmp ON c.company_idcompany = cmp.idcompany";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Retrieve this from customer table
            int id = rs.getInt("idcustomer");
            //Retrieve this from customer table
            String username = rs.getString("company_username");

            //Display values
            System.out.println("ID: " + id);
            System.out.println("Username: " + username);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the help! , what if i have multiple line of result ? how do i insert the id & username to a list and output it ? thank you :) 

Because i need to output it on other class so i need to return the list to that class. so i guess it need a array inside array right ?

Comment: Thanks i worked it out with your help above :) thanks !